# Remove Domain Name and Backslash from AD User

Tags: javascript

I have a user name that comes in like this `domain\user123`. I need to remove `domain\` and on have the username. I have tried the following:

```
var input = "domain\user123";

var str =  input.replace(/\\\//g, '')
```

and

```
var input = "domain\user123";

var str = input.replace('\\', '');
```

and

```
var input = "domain\user123";

var str = input.split('\\', '');
```

All come back with the backslash removed, but also the character after the backslash `domainser123`.

I need it to look like this `user123`.

Comment: If it's always `domain` then just remove it with a simple non-regex replace. If the word "domain" is just an example and it can vary, then you can use `/[^\\]+\\/`.

Comment: `var input = "domain\user123";` gives me the error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: malformed Unicode character escape sequence`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the domain and the `\`

```js
var input = "thisIsTheDomain\\user123";

var str = input.replace(/.*\\/, '');

console.log(str);
```

Alternatively, take the second index `[1]` of the `.split` method

```js
var input = "yetAnotherDomain\\user123";

var str = input.split('\\')[1];

console.log(str);
```

Comment: My input does not contain double backslashes `var input = "domain\\user123";` which I think is my issue. My input looks like this `var input = "domain\user123";` They domain name is just an example, there could be a number of domains.

Comment: @BrandonWilson for the first point, the "double backslashes", that is actually a single backslash when ran through JS. A single backslash is an [escape character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) when converts `\n` to a newline, `\t` to a tab, etc., and `\\` is how you print out a single `\`. Try it in the console, you have to use two each time you want one. For the second part, see my updated answer (which will come in a few minutes of posting this comment)